# Why does Microsoft Visual Basic skip over part of this code

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

I'm trying to make some labels on my Form to be visible, but i don't want to use a lot of `if` statements, but for some reason whenever i put `Me.Controls(lbl).Visbel = True` in a for or do loop it skips the whole loop. The code worked perfectly the way I wanted it until i got an error for calling `Dim lbl = Controls("Label" & counter_3)` for the whole class instead of in the From_load private sub. Sometimes i can get it to work, but only one label is visible

```
Dim chararray() As Char = word_list(random_word).ToCharArray
Dim lbl = "Label" & counter_3

    For Each item In chararray
        If item = Nothing Then
        Else
            word_list(counter_2) = item.ToString()
            counter_2 += 1
        End If
    Next

    For Each item In chararray
        If item = Nothing Then

        Else
            counter_3 += 1
            Me.Controls(lbl).Visible = True
            MsgBox(item & " " & counter_3)
        End If
    Next
```

I've also tried. In both the loops are completely skipped over. I know this because the MsgBox's don't appear.

```
Dim chararray() As Char = word_list(random_word).ToCharArray
Dim lbl = Controls("Label" & counter_3)

    For Each item In chararray
        If item = Nothing Then
        Else
            word_list(counter_2) = item.ToString()
            counter_2 += 1
        End If
    Next

    For Each item In chararray
        If item = Nothing Then

        Else
            counter_3 += 1
            lbl.Visble = True
            MsgBox(item & " " & counter_3)
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: If you throw an exception in WinForm event handler, it is usually caught and silently ignored. Try enabling 'Break on throw' in debugger for all of the C# exceptions.

Comment: Can you give me more detail about that, i'm still quite a beginer programmer and i'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Also, instead of the `If item = Nothing Then... ' no action... Else... Endif`, perhaps you should try `If item <> Nothing Then... Endif`. I'm not sure of how empty clauses in an `If` clause are handled in VB, but it's best to avoid empty conditional clauses in general. At the very least, they make your code harder to read.

Comment: I tried enabling 'break on throw' C# exceptions, but it still skips over the code

Answer (score 0):

The thing that I am noticing is that you are creating a `Char` array based on a random word returned from your word_list, you then iterate through the `Char` array using the count of the character in the array as an index into your word_list, if the amount of characters in your word exceeds the amount of words in your list you will get an  error and since this error is in the `Forms` Load event it will be swallowed and all the code after it will be aborted. There are also other issues that I would change like making sure all declarations have a type and I would probably use the [`Controls.Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find.aspx) Method instead and check that it has an actual object. But what I would probably do first is move your code to a separate Subroutine and call it after your `IntializeComponent` call in the Forms Constructor(`New`) Method.

Something like this.

```
Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

    YourMethod
End Sub


Public Sub YourMethod()
    Dim chararray() As Char = word_list(random_word).ToCharArray
    Dim lbl As Control() = Controls.Find("Label" & counter_3, True)

    For Each item In chararray
        If item = Nothing Then
        Else
            word_list(counter_2) = item.ToString()
            counter_2 += 1
        End If
    Next

    For Each item In chararray
        If item = Nothing Then

        Else
            counter_3 += 1
            If lbl.Length > 0 Then
                lbl(0).Visible = True
            Else
                MsgBox("Control not Found")
            End If
            MsgBox(item & " " & counter_3)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a good way to fix it. I already found a way around it though, but I will take this into consideration.

Comment: I will post my fix for this in 8 hours of posting this question.

Comment: @PygamePi That's fine,what I wanted to point out is that **any** error in the Form's Load EventHandler will be swallowed and not thrown causing any code after it not being run, you are better of using the Form's Constructor with a separate method as shown.

Comment: Ok i need to work on cleaner code anyway. mines a bit of a mess.